# I want to overlay bitmap on mediapipe facelandmarks using openCV, My code is not working

Tags: mediapipe, android, opencv

```
*/
```

This is my FaceMeshResultGlRenderer.

```
public class FaceMeshResultGlRenderer implements ResultGlRenderer<FaceMeshResult> {
    private Context mContext;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
public FaceMeshResultGlRenderer(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

private static final String TAG = "FaceMeshResultGlRenderer";

private static final float[] TESSELATION_COLOR = new float[]{0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f, 0.5f};
private static final int TESSELATION_THICKNESS = 5;
private static final float[] RIGHT_EYE_COLOR = new float[]{1f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f};
private static final int RIGHT_EYE_THICKNESS = 8;
private static final float[] RIGHT_EYEBROW_COLOR = new float[]{1f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f};
private static final int RIGHT_EYEBROW_THICKNESS = 8;
private static final float[] LEFT_EYE_COLOR = new float[]{0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f};
private static final int LEFT_EYE_THICKNESS = 8;
private static final float[] LEFT_EYEBROW_COLOR = new float[]{0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f};
private static final int LEFT_EYEBROW_THICKNESS = 8;
private static final float[] FACE_OVAL_COLOR = new float[]{0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1f};
private static final int FACE_OVAL_THICKNESS = 8;
private static final float[] LIPS_COLOR = new float[]{0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1f};
private static final int LIPS_THICKNESS = 8;
private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
        "uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;\n"
                + "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n"
                + "void main() {\n"
                + "  gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * vPosition;\n"
                + "}";
private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "precision mediump float;\n"
                + "uniform vec4 uColor;\n"
                + "void main() {\n"
                + "  gl_FragColor = uColor;\n"
                + "}";
private int program;
private int positionHandle;
private int projectionMatrixHandle;
private int colorHandle;
Bitmap bitmap;

private int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
    return shader;
}

@Override
public void setupRendering() {
    program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);



    positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    projectionMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uProjectionMatrix");
    colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uColor");

    //  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.eyelens);

    //chat


    float[] vertices = new float[] {
            0f, 0f,   // top left
            0f, 1f,   // bottom left
            1f, 0f,   // top right
            1f, 1f,   // bottom right
    };
    vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices).position(0);

    positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    projectionMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uProjectionMatrix");
    colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uColor");
    int textureHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uTexture");
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    // Set up bitmap texture
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.eyelens1);
    int[] textureIds = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
    int textureId = textureIds[0];
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureHandle, 0);
}

@Override
public void renderResult(FaceMeshResult result, float[] projectionMatrix) {
    if (result == null) {
        return;
    }
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixHandle, 1, false, projectionMatrix, 0);

    int numFaces = result.multiFaceLandmarks().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numFaces; ++i) {
        if (result.multiFaceLandmarks().get(i).getLandmarkCount()
                == FaceMesh.FACEMESH_NUM_LANDMARKS_WITH_IRISES) {
           /* drawLandmarks(
                    result.multiFaceLandmarks().get(i).getLandmarkList(),
                    FaceMeshConnections.FACEMESH_LEFT_IRIS,
                    LEFT_EYE_COLOR,
                    LEFT_EYE_THICKNESS);*/
            drawLandmarksWithOverlay( result.multiFaceLandmarks().get(i).getLandmarkList(), FaceMeshConnections.FACEMESH_LIPS,bitmap);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes the shader program.
 *
 * <p>This is only necessary if one wants to release the program while keeping the context around.
 */
public void release() {
    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
}


private void drawLandmarksWithOverlay(List<NormalizedLandmark> faceLandmarkList, ImmutableSet<FaceMeshConnections.Connection> connections, Bitmap overlayBitmap) {
    // Convert the bitmap to a Mat object
    Mat overlayMat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(overlayBitmap, overlayMat);

    // Loop over each connection in the list
    for (FaceMeshConnections.Connection c : connections) {
        NormalizedLandmark start = faceLandmarkList.get(c.start());
        NormalizedLandmark end = faceLandmarkList.get(c.end());

        // Calculate the midpoint between the two landmarks
        int landmarkX = (int) ((start.getX() + end.getX()) / 2);
        int landmarkY = (int) ((start.getY() + end.getY()) / 2);


        // Define the ROI around the landmark
        int size = 2000000; // adjust this as needed
        Rect roi = new Rect(landmarkX - size/2, landmarkY - size/2, size, size);

        // Create a new Mat object that is a copy of the ROI from the original image
        Mat roiMat = new Mat(overlayMat, roi).clone();


        // Convert the ROI Mat object to a Bitmap
        Bitmap roiBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(roiMat.cols(), roiMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(roiMat, roiBitmap);

        // Create a new Canvas object for the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(roiBitmap);

        // Draw the overlay image on the canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        // Convert the modified bitmap back to a Mat object
        Utils.bitmapToMat(roiBitmap, roiMat);

        // Replace the original ROI with the modified Mat object
        roiMat.copyTo(new Mat(overlayMat, roi));
    }

    // Convert the modified Mat object back to a Bitmap and update the texture
    Utils.matToBitmap(overlayMat, overlayBitmap);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, overlayBitmap, 0);
}
```

}

I am calling this in my main activity.

```
 private void setupStreamingModePipeline(InputSource inputSource) {
this.inputSource = inputSource;
// Initializes a new MediaPipe Face Mesh solution instance in the streaming mode.
facemesh =
    new FaceMesh(
        this,
        FaceMeshOptions.builder()
            .setStaticImageMode(false)
            .setRefineLandmarks(true)
            .setRunOnGpu(RUN_ON_GPU)
            .build());
facemesh.setErrorListener((message, e) -> Log.e(TAG, "MediaPipe Face Mesh error:" + message));

if (inputSource == InputSource.CAMERA) {
  cameraInput = new CameraInput(this);
  cameraInput.setNewFrameListener(textureFrame -> facemesh.send(textureFrame));
} else if (inputSource == InputSource.VIDEO) {
  videoInput = new VideoInput(this);
  videoInput.setNewFrameListener(textureFrame -> facemesh.send(textureFrame));
}

// Initializes a new Gl surface view with a user-defined FaceMeshResultGlRenderer.
glSurfaceView = new SolutionGlSurfaceView<>(this, facemesh.getGlContext(), facemesh.getGlMajorVersion());
glSurfaceView.setSolutionResultRenderer(new FaceMeshResultGlRenderer(this));
glSurfaceView.setRenderInputImage(true);
facemesh.setResultListener(
    faceMeshResult -> {
      logNoseLandmark(faceMeshResult, /*showPixelValues=*/ false);
      glSurfaceView.setRenderData(faceMeshResult);
      glSurfaceView.requestRender();
    });

// The runnable to start camera after the gl surface view is attached.
// For video input source, videoInput.start() will be called when the video uri is available.
if (inputSource == InputSource.CAMERA) {
  glSurfaceView.post(this::startCamera);
}

// Updates the preview layout.
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.preview_display_layout);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
frameLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
frameLayout.addView(glSurfaceView);
glSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
frameLayout.requestLayout();
```

}

No Overlay is happening, I can just see my face.